# How to select a text with double-click in a web page via Selenium in Python? (Not available Xpath, ID, etc.)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have boxes like this:

https://prnt.sc/ofbs2y

Xpath value for the space next to the "Axles":

```
// * [@ id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ABC_ctl02"]
```

Xpath value for the space next to the "Classic":

```
// * [@ id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ABC_ctl03_"]
```

There is only one difference in the number at the end, but these are not specific values. Sorting can vary according to each user. This ranking might look like this:

https://prnt.sc/ofbtdk

The Xpath value for the space value next to the "Classic", which is the fourth row here

```
// * [@ id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ABC_ctl05_"]
```

The Xpath value changes according to the sorting, not the name on the left. This prevents me from using values like Xpath and ID. As a solution, I plan to switch to the corresponding box by selecting the Classic value with double-click and pressing the TAB key. By the way Classic is just so name. The real name there might be something like “Classic of the year". In fact, I can also choose the entire "Classic of the year" phrase.

By the way, sorting thing is valid for the Axles, Classic, etc. too. That's why I can't choose Axles or Classic with Xpath, ID. Because, like boxes, these values do not have specific Xpath or ID values.

For these reasons, I would like to double-click the word "Axles" on the page and switch to the tab with the TAB key. Is it possible?

HTML data of Axles:

```
<tr style="color:Black;background-color:#EEEEEE;">
                                <td>Project</td><td>L-Axles</td><td>LTS Axles</td><td>-</td><td>
                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_lblRndmi" style="display:inline-block;width:60px;">R&D</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pcCalismaSaatGiris$ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni$wgrKulalniciFavori$ctl08$txtSaatBinaIci" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_txtSaatBinaIci" disabled="disabled" class="numeric" onfocus="toplaYeni(this,event)" onblur="toplaYeni(this,event)" onkeydown="OnlyDecimal(this);" onKeyUp="toplaYeni(this,event);" style="background-color:Gainsboro;width:30px;" />
                            </td><td>
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pcCalismaSaatGiris$ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni$wgrKulalniciFavori$ctl08$txtSaatTesvikKapsamiUstu" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_txtSaatTesvikKapsamiUstu" disabled="disabled" class="numeric" onfocus="toplaYeni(this,event)" onblur="toplaYeni(this,event)" onkeydown="OnlyDecimal(this);" onKeyUp="toplaYeni(this,event);" style="background-color:Gainsboro;width:30px;" />
                            </td><td>
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pcCalismaSaatGiris$ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni$wgrKulalniciFavori$ctl08$txtSaatBinaDisi" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_txtSaatBinaDisi" disabled="disabled" class="numeric" onfocus="toplaYeni(this,event);" onblur="toplaYeni(this,event);" onkeydown="OnlyDecimal(this);" onKeyUp="toplaYeni(this,event); binaDisiControl(this);" style="background-color:Gainsboro;width:30px;" />
                            </td><td>
                                <table class="dxeButtonEdit dxeDisabled" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri" border="0" style="background-color:Gainsboro;width:150px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="display:none;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri_VI" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri_VI" type="hidden" /></td><td class="dxic" style="width:100%;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;"><input tabindex="-1" class="dxeEditArea dxeDisabled dxeEditAreaSys" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri_I" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pcCalismaSaatGiris$ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni$wgrKulalniciFavori$ctl08$drpGorevTipleri" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" type="text" style="background-color:Gainsboro;height:15px;cursor:default;" /></td><td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri_B-1" class="dxeButtonEditButton dxeDisabled dxeButtonDisabled"><table class="dxbebt" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="dx"><img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_drpGorevTipleri_B-1Img" class="dxEditors_edtDropDownDisabled" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_5-jljth" alt="v" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td><td>
                                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pcCalismaSaatGiris$ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni$wgrKulalniciFavori$ctl08$txtSaat" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori_ctl08_txtSaat" class="numeric" onfocus="FBorder(this)" onblur="BBorder(this)" onmousedown="return false;" onkeydown="OnlyDecimal(this);" style="width:30px;" />
                            </td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML code please?

Comment: I added html data of a value which is Axles. Since the entire data size is too high, I just added the html data of a single value. Axles's Xpath value is: //*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pcCalismaSaatGiris_ucCalismaSaatiGuncelleYeni_wgrKulalniciFavori"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[3].
 There is no specific value here. Only difference is "8" number in Xpath.

Comment: @KnightKronos Are you able to identify the labels besides the text boxes uniquely using xpath? if so, then you can easily try following sibling approach to click on the next test box. You don't need ID or name of the text boxes.